# Problem binding hostname to website on IIS

Tags: iis, binding, hostname, nameservers

I have a Windows server 2016 with IIS. I've added forward lookup zone on **DNS manager** and added two Host(A) records for ns1 and ns2. I also added two **NameServer** as ns1.mydomain1.com and ns2.mydomain1.com.

I have another domain as mydomain2.com and set this dns to ns1.mydomain1.com and ns2.mydomain1.com. If I'm binding site to mydomain1.com it's worked but when binding to mydomain2.com it does not work.

It is mentioned, I have set dns of mydomain1.com to ip of server.

Comment: I suggest you could check the computer which is inside the domain2.com could accessed the IIS server by ID address. Then I suggest you could check the ns1.mydomain1.com has added the right IP address to forward the request to the IIS server .

Comment: Some very basic diagnostics should show you what's wrong, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html